# How to limit Django URL parameter to a list of options?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the following URL in my project:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('case/<str:type>/<int:id>/', views.case, name='case'),
    ...
]
```

It works fine, but the `type` URL parameter can literally only have 2 values in my database: `"internal"` and `"external"`. How can I limit this in my URL path itself? Would save me from having to validate it in the view. Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions the `url` or `re_path` is using regex so you could write a small regex for your case and use `re_path/url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.urls import include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'case/(?P<type>\binternal\b|\bexternal\b)/<int:id>/', views.case, name='case'),
    ...
]
```

Let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

You could create a decorator that sits over the view that validates the type value in the url string.

IE raise 404 if type not in allowed list.